# React SVG component render dynamically

Tags: reactjs, svg, create-react-app

I'm building a local weather app on React via Create React App and I need to render weather icon dynamically based on a type of weather. I have this code:

```
import React from 'react';

import { ReactComponent as MistIcon } from 'assets/img/weather/mist.svg';
import { ReactComponent as RainIcon } from 'assets/img/weather/rain.svg';
import { ReactComponent as SnowIcon } from 'assets/img/weather/snow.svg';

const icon = (props) => {

    const { weatherType } = props;

    const WeatherIconName = `${weatherType}Icon`; //Rain or Snow or Mist etc


    return(

        <Icon size={'lg'}>
            <WeatherIconName/> //here I'm trying to render <MistIcon/> or <SnowIcon/> or <RainIcon/>
        </Icon>

    );

};

export default icon;
```

And it just throws an error like that: *Warning: The tag  is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.*

But if I name it explicitly, like this, it works and renders a proper icon:

```
return(

  <Icon size={'lg'}>
     <MistIcon/>
  </Icon>

);
```

Help me please to enhance my code to render icons dynamically if it possible. Sorry if the question is stypid, I'm a newbie in React.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a simple object as a dictionary to map `weatherType` to the specific icon:

```
const ICONS_WEATHER = {
  Mist: <MistIcon />,
  Rain: <RainIcon />,
  Snow: <SnowIcon />
};

const icon = props => {
  const { weatherType } = props;

  return <Icon size={'lg'}>{ICONS[weatherType] || <DefaultIcon />}</Icon>;
};

export default icon;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works and I'm soooo happy! =)

Answer (score 1):

If you have many weather types, you can create a new component for handling them. 
([Code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-taussig-2crh6?fontsize=14))

**index.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import WeatherIcon from "./icon";

function App() {

  const weatherType = 'sunny'; // props hardcoded, change to 'rainy'

  return (
    <div>
      <WeatherIcon name={weatherType} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**icon.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import { ReactComponent as Rainy } from "./rainy.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Sunny } from "./sunny.svg";

const iconTypes = {
  rainy: Rainy,
  sunny: Sunny
};

const IconComponent = ({ name, ...props }) => {
  let Icon = iconTypes[name];
  return <Icon {...props} />;
};

export default IconComponent;
```

In your case, you'd end up using

```
return(

  <Icon size={'lg'}>
     <WeatherIcon name={weatherType} />
  </Icon>

);
```